# JQuery search for strings in array

Tags: jquery

Via textfield (id="preset_searchfield") I can search my table by jquery. Only the Rows that contain the search-text are visible:

```
    $("#tab_body tr").hide();
    $("#tab_body tr td:contains('" + $("#preset_searchfield").val() + "')").each(function(){
        $(this).parent().show();
    });
```

This is working. Now I want to search multiple words divided by a space. Therefore I split the searchstring like this:

```
    var searchString = $("#preset_searchfield").val();
    var searchArray = searchString.split(' ');
```

What do I have to do in order to make all rows visible that contain words from my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is use `jQuery.filter()` method

```
/* more efficient to loop over each row, and look at TD's within row*/
$('#tab_body tr').filter(function(){
   var isMatch=false, $cells=$(this).children();
   $.each(searchArray, function(i, searchStr){
      /* check if any of cells contain this search string*/
      if( $cells.filter(':contains('+searchStr+')').length){
           isMatch=true;
           /* stop looking at other values in array, found a match*/
          return false;
      }
   })
  return isMatch;
}).show();
```

Comment: thanks, but after typing a space nothing is visible. Also nothing is visible when the searchfield is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: create a live demo showing how you are using code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: pretty sure I know what problem is... you need to trim whitespace from search input...otherwise end up with one array item is just `space`. Or check that array doesn't have `" "` in it

Comment: basic filter works fine here with static input value  http://jsfiddle.net/jqwm8/1/

Comment: also assumes you want any word in array...not necessarily in same row if more than one word

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too

```
var searchString = $("#preset_searchfield").val();
var searchArray = searchString.split(' ');

for (x in searchArray) {
    $('#tab_body tr:contains(' + searchArray[x] + ')').hide();
}
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jqwm8/

Comment: performance wise will have to loop over whole table for every word...could be expensive on big table

Comment: @charlietfl hey tnx.. dint think that way.. will keep that in mind :)